# Scala, couchbase - convert AsyncN1qlQueryResult into custom object

Tags: scala, couchbase, sql++

I have a `case class` with simple data:

```
case class MyClass(
  details: Details,
  names: List[String],
  id: String,
)
```

I have created a couchbase query which should retrieve all documents from database:

```
 val query = s"SELECT * from `docs`"
      for {
        docs<- bucket
          .query(N1qlQuery.simple(query))
          .flatMap((rows: AsyncN1qlQueryResult) => rows.rows())          
          .toList
          .parse[F]
          .map(_.asScala.toList)
      } yield docs
```

`parse[F]` is a simple function to convert from `Observable`. The problem here is that I got an error `type mismatch` which says that found `List[AsyncN1qlQueryResult]` instead of required `List[MyClass]`. How should I convert from `AsyncN1qlQueryResult` into `MyClass` objects?
I'm using `Circe` to parse documents.

Comment: All you have to do is implicit custom conversion for this type.

Comment: Can you show the result if you'll `println(AsyncN1qlQueryResult)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to report that there is now an early release of the native Couchbase Scala SDK available, which does include support for converting each row result of a N1QL query directly into your case class:

```
case class Address(line1: String)
case class User(name: String, age: Int, addresses: Seq[Address])
object User {
  // Define a Codec so SDK knows how to convert User to/from JSON
  implicit val codec: Codec[User] = Codecs.codec[User]
}

val statement = """select * from `users`;"""

val rows: Try[Seq[User]] = cluster.query(statement)
  .map(result => result
    .rows.flatMap(row => 
      row.contentAs[User].toOption)) 

rows match {
  case Success(rows: Seq[User]) =>
    rows.foreach(row => println(row))
  case Failure(err) =>
    println(s"Error: $err")
}
```

This is the blocking API. There's also APIs to allow getting the results as Futures, or as Flux/Monos from Reactive Programming, so you have a lot of flexibility on how to get the data.

You can see how to get started here: https://docs.couchbase.com/scala-sdk/1.0alpha/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html

Please note that this is an alpha release to let the community get an idea where we're heading with it and give them an opportunity to provide feedback.  It shouldn't be used in production.  The forums (https://forums.couchbase.com/) are the best place to raise any feedback you have.

Comment: Could it be use via `sbt` also?

Comment: Indeed it can.  These instructions will be included in the docs for the next release:

    resolvers += "Couchbase Snapshots" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"
    libraryDependencies += "com.couchbase.client" %% "scala-client" % "1.0.0-alpha.1"